# Render 3d object (cube) with image target from unity3d (vuforia) to ios?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Here I am new to vuforia qualcomm projects for AR. I used unity3d to generate project (image Target framwork). After built and run app from unity3d the ios app able to render camera on screen but after moving camera on target image it's not render the 3d object(cube)

I visited link: [vuforia Portal](http://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/getting-started-ios-native-sdk)
And go through step by step process:

1. Add vuforia extension in unity3d.
2. Add target manager to database.
3. download package and import it to an unity3d.
4. drag image target to scene and select the dataset to downloaded package.
5. add cude as 3d object into image target.
6. built and run app in ios.

The camera render on screen but on the same image target not display cube in 3d.
Also. My unity3d not generating file format as given in sample applications in vuforia.

Please help regarding this.

Comment: do u have idea about drag and drop 3D object on camera view and tracking without any marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled the dataset in the ARCamera as well?

Nad

Answer (score 0):

@, VinuPriya...

If you are not using marker, you should use OpenCv framework to detect object where you want to place your 3d object. I have not Implement drag drop for 3d object. I use on click change 3d objects